# Как запустить docker-compose без sudo?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Есть следующий сетап:
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./apache.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
```

Dockerfile (находится в корне проекта):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
  && export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install apache2
RUN apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-cli php-xdebug php7.0-mbstring sqlite3 php7.0-mysql php-imagick php-memcached php-pear curl imagemagick php7.0-dev php7.0-phpdbg php7.0-gd npm nodejs-legacy php7.0-json php7.0-curl php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-intl apache2 vim git-core wget libsasl2-dev libssl-dev libsslcommon2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev autoconf g++ make openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libsasl2-dev libpcre3-dev \
  && a2enmod headers \
  && a2enmod rewrite

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
RUN rm $APACHE_PID_FILE -f
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log
RUN mkdir -p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR

VOLUME [ "/var/www/html" ]
WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/apache2" ]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Вообще, я пытаюсь поднять проект на Laravel в контейнере (это так, может кто скинет свои наработки по данному поводу). В общем, происходит следующее:

```
$ docker-compose up --build                                                                                                                                            Building webserver
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

Через sudo все работает, но хотелось бы узнать, почему это не работает без привелегированного пользователя, ведь:

```
$ docker run hello-world                                                                                                                                             
Hello from Docker!
.....
```

Comment: а вы пробовали проделать предложенное в ответе?

Comment: поиск строки с ошибкой выдаёт такие ссылки: [1](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1214) и [2](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181)

Answer (score 2):

Что бы иметь возможность запускать докер не от рута, нужно добавить себя к нему в группу - https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

- создадим группу, если ее нет

  sudo groupadd docker
- добавим себя (можно указать явно своего пользователя)

  sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
- перезапустим демона (некоторым почему то это не помогает и они перезапускают машину. Грубо, но работает:) ).

  sudo service docker restart

Comment: см. последние 5 строк, я могу запустить докер...

Comment: У меня трабл еще в том что докер могу запустить без судо, а докер-композ нет

Answer (score 0):

Всетаки, проблема была в докере.

Для того, чтобы наткнуться на истинную проблему, нужно было сбилдить докерфайл, он мне выдал уже другую ошибку, которую я уже исправил (удалил подключенный раздел к бд .data).